# Accessing C# Dictionary and return value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<ICD_Map2, string> maps = new Dictionary<ICD_Map2, string>();
```

I add to the dictionary via button click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maps.Clear();
    // Load mapping file.
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"Call_Details_Map.csv"));
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        maps.Add(new ICD_Map2(values[0].Replace("\"",""), values[1].Replace("\"","")), values[2].Replace("\"",""));
    }
}
```

I want to use LINQ and map my keys to the "string" in maps.

How do I do it?

```
var File001 = from line in File.ReadLines(ICD_process)
              let l = line.Split(',')
              where l[0] != "\"Statement Date\""
              select new
              {
                  CallType = maps.ToLookup(p => l[5], p => l[3]),
                  Calls = l[11] == "\"\"" ? "0" : (maps.ToLookup(p => l[5], p => l[3]) == "Mobile Data" || maps.ToLookup(p => l[5], p => l[3]) == "Mobile SMS") ? "0" : l[11].Replace("\"","").ToString())
              };
```

I am getting error in Calls variable in File001 Linq method

Comment: what is the value in dictionary? Could you elaborate more? the sample key and value in your map, input and expected output?

Comment: @CuongLe my Dictionary looks like:
"Mobile SMS" | "Australia" | "Text";
"Mobile SMS" | "International" | "Overseas Text";
"Mobile SMS" | "Other" | "Mobile SMS";

Comment: @CuongLe yes this is the value that i add into the dictionary

Comment: Check your code again, the method button_click even cannot compile because you did not add value to dic?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but here is my advice. Now you are working with spitted lines array like this `l[0] != "\"Statement Date\""`. I think only you know what data should be at index 9. It's not very readable, error-prone (typo in `Statemnet Date`, wrong index), and it's very hard to maintain. Instead this create an object, which will parse line for you and provide data via strongly typed properties with nice names.

```
public class ICDEntry
{
    public static ICDEntry CreateFrom(string line)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        var entry = new ICDEntry();
        // assign values to properties:
        // if (values[0] == "\"Statement Date\"")
        //     entry.StatementDate = DateTime.Parse(values[1]);
        //     entry.IsSomething = values[11] == "\"\""
        return entry;
    }

    public DateTime? StatementDate { get; private set; }
    public string MobileSMS { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSomething { get; private set; }
}
```

Now you can parse each line, and then work in strongly typed world making queries to your ICD entries:

```
var entries = File.ReadLines(ICD_process).Select(l => ICDEntry.CreateFrom(l));
var File001 = from e in entries
              where e.StatementDate.HasValue
              select new {
                  Calls = e.IsSomething ? "0" : e.MobileSMS; // use ICDEntry here
              };
```